# Getting an error with my servlet at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0

Tags: java

Getting a error and it looks like something is wrong with my constructor? In my ProfileServelt, I have a default constructor that creates a hashmap and then creates 3 profiles. For me it looks fine and it doesn't seem to have anything wrong but maybe I'm missing something? I have checked online for solutions but with no luck

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [ProfileServlet]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ntrut.ProfileServlet.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

my code

```
@WebServlet("/ProfileServlet")
public class ProfileServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
 HashMap<String, Profile> team = new HashMap<String, Profile>();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Gson gson = null;

ProfileServlet() 
{

    Profile profile1 = new Profile("1","bob","bee","Manc city","21");
    Profile profile2 = new Profile("2","billy","smith","Dortmud","25");
    Profile profile3 = new Profile("3","john","jamesd","Aston Villa","44");

    String id = "1";
    String id2 = "2";
    String id3 = "3";

    team.put(id,profile1);
    team.put(id2,profile2);
    team.put(id3,profile3);
}

public void sendAsJson(HttpServletResponse response, Object obj) throws IOException
{
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    String js = gson.toJson(obj);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

    out.print(js);
    out.flush();

}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String path = request.getPathInfo();
    out.print(path);

    sendAsJson(response, team);

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{




}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried adding a `public` access modifier to the constructor?

Comment: i just tried it and it worked, cant believe i send 2 hours on this....